# flutter doctor: unable to find the bundled java version

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

[image]

I have updated my system variables and put the path of my java JDK bin files there but it dosen't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the file "java" following the path where Error is shown.
2. Then right click on the file and go to Properties.
3. Then Go to permissions and Check the box "Allow executing file as
   program".
4. Finally, `run flutter doctor` to see No issues found!.

**other wise if you not installed java**

1. install java
2. set path of java in **Eviormental** variable.
3. Finally, `run flutter doctor` to see No issues found!.